# Close an expanded row in a Vuetify v-data-table through code

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a v-data-table that expands to show additional information and am trying to find a way, through code, to close the row before the user refreshes the data.  Is there some event I can emit up to get any open rows to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expanded.sync` to retrieve all the expanded rows in a data table and to close all the rows that have been expanded, just reset the synched variable to an empty array.

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :expanded.sync="expanded"
    item-key="name"
    show-expand
    class="elevation-1"
  >
</v-data-table>
```

```
  data(){
    return {
       ...
       expanded: [] 
    }
  }
  methods: {
    ...
    closeAll(){
       this.expanded = []
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow I typed that into the browser as a test so fast I misspelled expanded, that does the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the `expanded` prop existed back in 1.5. If anyone else is looking for that, this seems to work: `this.$refs.dataTable._data.expanded = {};` where you have `ref="dataTable"` on your `v-data-table`.

That `expanded` field is an object e.g. `{ "yourExpandedRowItemId": true }` so resetting it collapses any open rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :expanded.sync="expanded"
    item-key="name.last"
    group-by="country"
    >
    <template v-slot:group.header="{ group, headers, toggle, isOpen }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">
            <v-btn @click="toggle" small icon :ref="group" :data-open="isOpen">
                <v-icon v-if="isOpen">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
                <v-icon v-else>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            {{ group }}
        </td>
    </template></v-data-table>

  closeAll () {
    Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach(k => {
        console.log(this.$refs[k])
        if (this.$refs[k] && this.$refs[k].$attrs['data-open']) {
            this.$refs[k].$el.click()
        }
    })
},
```

this is perfectly working for a close all expand by a "separate button outside a table " #vue2